# Generate a set of tuples from one tuple in PIG

Tags: hadoop, tuples, apache-pig, flatten

I couldn't find any solution how to generate in **Pig** a set of tuples from one tuple according to the rule:

**Input:**

```
((1,2,3),(a,b,c),(aaa,bbb,ccc))
```

**Output:**

```
(1,a,aaa)
(2,b,bbb)
(3,c,ccc)
```

Suppose TOBAG and FLATTEN should be applied, but it seems too tricky.

Comment: Post your entire script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `zip` builtin function and argument unpacking ("star" args):

```
>>> x = ((1,2,3),('a','b','c'),('aaa','bbb','ccc'))

>>> tuple(zip(*x))
((1, 'a', 'aaa'), (2, 'b', 'bbb'), (3, 'c', 'ccc'))

>>> for y in zip(*x):
    print(y)

(1, 'a', 'aaa')
(2, 'b', 'bbb')
(3, 'c', 'ccc')
```

Answer (score 1):

`[tuple(original[i] for original in originals) for i in range(len(original[0]))]`
 will give you the second list of tuples if your original list is called `originals`.